# Raise user control click when hitting a control inside

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've created an user control with some labels and pictures inside.

Then, I added this user control to a form.

In the form events, I've set the UserControl_click event to raise a function.

The problem I'm having is, if I click to the UserControl background, where there's no label nor pictures, the function is raised. But if I click to a label or to a picture inside the control, the function doesn't raise.

I want the same behavior when clicking a control inside my user control than when clicking the control background.

Comment: could you explain why you would want clicking on a label to act the same way as when you click on the background of a form? your last sentence threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the add the function on each control click event inside your UserControl:

```
Public Event ControlClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Private Sub uc1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For each elem As Control in Me.Controls
        AddHandler elem.Click, AddressOf RaiseClick
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub RaiseClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ControlClick(sender, e)
End Sub
```

And then outside just catch both events:

```
Public Sub UserControl_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                           Handles UserControl1.Click, UserControl1.ControlClick
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @SysDragon, that solved my question. The fact is, I have only 6 user controls, then I can handle each of the events. Could you clarify how to handle this if you have an unknown number of user controls to handle their events?

Comment: I dont know if I understand you. You mean the controls inside your `UserControl`? Anyway, the code here is for an undetermined number of controls inside the UserControl. If you want to handle the events of different user controls just add the handlers with the function, with `Handlers UC1.Click, UC2.Click, UC3.Click` etc, or manually with `AddHandler` method.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say for an unknown number of user controls UC1...UCn, the piece of code in uc1_load event really assign the event for every control inside the user control. Anyway, you answered my question, I can do it by adding the handlers dinamically with AddHandler method for each UserControl control type. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your labels capture click events. Subscribe for their Click events and call the same handler that you call from UserControl_click.